# Flask reqparse.RequestParser ValueError with parse_args()

Tags: python, flask, post, python-requests

Good day everyone,

I am having a really strange issue with Flask's `RequestParser.parse_args()`. Below is a snippet of my `__init__` method of the relevant class:

```
def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2
    self.arg_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    self.arg_parser.add_argument('optional_arg_from_url', type=bool, default=False)
```

Notice I only add 1 argument to `self.arg_parser`. Then, in the `post` method, I want to retrieve `optional_arg_from_url` with `arg_parser.parse_args()` as follows:

```
def post(self):

    # Authorization in headers
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization').split()[1]

    # Parse args
    args = self.arg_parser.parse_args()
    optional_arg_from_url = args['optional_arg_from_url']
```

Now, an example of the request url containing the optional arg would look as follows:

`http://localhost:8080/path/to/endpoint/?optional_arg_from_url=True`

The error that I am getting is `ValueError: not enough values to unpack: expected 2`, which is raised when `args = self.arg_parser.parse_args()` is called. I don't understand why 2 values are expected, since I only add one argument to the parser. Also, why would a value error be raised when I try to parse the args? Shouldn't it just parse all the args regardless?

Another interesting thing, is that the corresponding unit tests are working, regardless of whether the optional arg is included in the url or not. The code ALSO works if I do not include the optional arg in the url (which means the arg defaults to `False`) and gets parsed correspondingly. It is just when I try to overwrite the arg's value to `True` within the request url when a value error is raised.

I also made sure that `optional_arg_from_url` is spelled exactly the same everywhere, so that is not the issue.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Your init is requiring two arguments, is it not? So where is your second?

Comment: Good point, those 2 args are provided when the class is added as a resource to the flask client: 

`api.add_resource(MyAPI, endpoint='my_endpoint',
                 resource_class_args=(arg1, arg2,), strict_slashes=False)`

Comment: I know I've always used `request.args.get(arg_name, default_value)` when grabbing args from a URL during a call. Perhaps that would be found to be easier?

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try that and see if it works.

Comment: @user3832673 thanks a lot, `request.args.get(arg_name, default_value)` solved the problem for me 